# How to scale area in violin plot to counts

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I am trying to create a violin plot and overlay data from year 1 with data from year 2. However, since the sample size is the same in year 1 and year 2 I expected the area of the violin to be equal. This does not seem to be the case, if you look at the included screenshot. Is there a way to scale area with regards to counts in matplotlib?

I have looked at seaborn violin plot with the split option and scale='count', but if there is a way to scale in matplotlib I prefer the overlay.

EDIT: I noticed that the plot looks the same with seaborn, scale='count', so I guess the scaling is not the problem? Is there a way of making the areas equal?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

year1 = [0.31686211, 0.39691523, 0.28396513, 0.35692174, 0.28013689, 0.40459902, 0.3020441, 0.34157149]
year2 = [0.18479367, 0.30268128, 0.25940495, 0.39964962, 0.32782555, 0.28997294, 0.31437325, 0.36121367]

plt.violinplot(year1)
plt.violinplot(year2)
```

[violin plot with overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK8tY.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the `scale=` parameter of `sns.violinplot` to work, all data need to be provided at the same time.  The easiest way is to create a ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) dataframe with all the data.

In the example below, I reduced the number of entries for the second year, to have an example with unequal counts.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

year1 = [0.31686211, 0.39691523, 0.28396513, 0.35692174, 0.28013689, 0.40459902, 0.3020441, 0.34157149]
# year2 = [0.18479367, 0.30268128, 0.25940495, 0.39964962, 0.32782555, 0.28997294, 0.31437325, 0.36121367]
year2 = [0.18479367, 0.30268128, 0.25940495, 0.39964962]
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['year1'] * len(year1) + ['year2'] * len(year2),
                   'value': year1 + year2})
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='year', y='value', scale='count')
plt.show()
```

[image: violinplot with counts]

The same plot (without the automatic labeling) can also be created without a dataframe:

```py
sns.violinplot(x=['year1'] * len(year1) + ['year2'] * len(year2),
               y=year1 + year2,
               scale='count')
```